# Direct3D over Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, direct3d

How can I get Direct3D to work over a Remote Desktop connection? I am using Windows XP Professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D acceleration does not work on Remote Desktop or in Virtual PC/Server. 
Software-rendered OpenGL works on both Remote Desktop and Virtual PC/Server.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think OpenGL 1.1 is the only version that has software support... Can't run shaders with that. SwiftShader is a better option.

Comment: I think you are right that only OpenGL 1.1 is supported.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Try this. From your desktop, run any 3d windows accelerated program in windowed mode. A game, a demoscene demo, a WebGL demo in Chrome or Firefox. With it still running, go to another machine and remote in to the first machine. The app will keep running just fine over remote desktop. This just seems like a bug in RDP :(

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use D3D9 over remote desktop in two different ways. I have done & tested both.

(This runs fast)
The best way is to use SwiftShader, a software implementation of D3D9. This should run in any color bit. https://opensource.google/projects/swiftshader

(NOTE: This is very slow)
The second is to install the DirectX SDK on the remote computer. Your app must create a D3D9 reference device & the remote computer must be set to 16bit color.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already knew this but doesn't look like this is a supported scenario.

See 
[Remote Desktop Sharing Disables Direct3D Functionality](http://web.archive.org/web/20120428201450/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260565)
and
[Is it too much to ask to have ONE good image display API in Windows?](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=146)

You may want to look at WPF if you have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I start the 3D program *first* in the local machine, and I later get the session using remote desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [VirtualGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualGL) for this purpose, if you like OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article Direct3D is possible (but dog slow) when the box you're remoting into is running Vista.

http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=208

I haven't verified this and cannot personally vouch for whether or not it REALLY works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tim's answer, in the WPF Futures talk at PDC a member of the D3D team mentioned that D3D 10 under Windows 7 would work with remoting and will be remoted by primitives (which leads me to believe that the client doing the remoting would handle the rendering). They don't give much information, but it's touched on in the Q&A section of the WPF Futures talk (PC07) which you can check out on microsoftpdc.com.

Doesn't solve the D3D9 in XP question, but remote desktop with D3D10 under Windows 7 sounds a little better. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it does work if the server is running Vista.